# How to run angular app from Intellij idea 2017.1?

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

How can I set run my angular 2 application from Intellij Idea run configuration menu?

From terminal I just put `ng serve` but what should I select from list of configurations from Intellij Idea?

Comment: What about `start`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

One way to do it is to create a scripts entry in your `package.json`, if it's not already there:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "node_modules/.bin/ng",
    "start": "ng serve -o -lr=false"
  },
  ...
}
```

This will open the browser, and disable live-reloading (if that's what you would like.. If not, remove the `-lr` option). This will also use a locally installed `angular-cli`. This way you don't have to install it globally

Then create a new run configuration and choose `npm`.

- Select your package.json
- Select run command
- Select the script `start`

Make sure your node interpreter is set, and press `ok`.

Now you can use the green button to run your configuration :)

You can also just right-click on your `package.json`, and select `show npm scripts`. This will open a window, where you can double click the 'start' script you just created

Comment: Thank you much! This is exactly what I want.